# Handle SQL SUM operator on varchar operands

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, varchar

I want to calculate aggregate functions **SUM** and **COUNT** on some table columns. The problem is that the columns are selected dynamically and hence they can be of **varchar** type. In this situation, COUNT is appliable but SUM isn't. How can I handle this using SQL? I want somthing like:

`IF varcharColumn IS typeof(varchar) THEN -1 ELSE SUM(varcharColumn`)

Comment: sum will work only on numeric datatype column .

Comment: It's not clear that. You want to avoid the `SUM` if it's a `varchar` column, or actually `CONCAT` the values for those columns?

Comment: Which Database is it.

Comment: @Alireza: I want to avoid SUM if the column is of type varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @varCharColumn VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 varcharColumn FROM SomeTable)

IF (ISNUMERIC(@varCharColumn) = 1 )
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(varcharColumn) AS CountNumber, SUM(varcharColumn) AS SumNumber
    FROM SomeTable
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(varcharColumn) AS CountNumber, -1 AS SumNumber
    FROM SomeTable
END
```

Here are some info on [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Comment: Compile time error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

Comment: sorry, fixed my answer

Comment: I execute the following query but still the same error: SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(log) = 1 THEN SUM(log) ELSE -1 END AS SUMC FROM [Logs]

Comment: Darka: unfortunately the error still exist: my query is: DECLARE @vcc VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 command FROM [Log]) IF (ISNUMERIC(@vcc) = 1 ) BEGIN SELECT COUNT(command) AS COUNTC,SUM(command) AS SUMC FROM [Log] END ELSE BEGIN SELECT COUNT(command) AS COUNTC FROM [Log] END

Comment: @Darka : In my query I avoid SUM for varchar types. Why it still gets error!!

Comment: what error and maybe you mean that you have not only numeric, but also varchar values in one column?

Comment: still says "Operand data type varchar(MAX) is invalid for SUM operator". It seems that ISNUMERIC always return 1

Comment: I have checked, when I gave text field it gave 0. So as I guessed you have both types in same column?

Comment: for testing purposes can you add where clause to first select (with `SUM`): `WHERE ISNUMERIC(@vcc) = 1 `

Comment: the **command** column that I use in ISNUMERIC, can only gets bellow strings: INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE. It only has text fields

Comment: what result you get here @vcc

Comment: @Darka: ISNUMERIC works fine, vcc is 0 and the part that calculate SUM is not running, but I don't know why it gets error on SUM?! maybe we should cast it?!